# EXE upload prevention 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement EXE file upload prevention in my project in the same way as it is implemented in gmail (even if EXE file is within a password protected zip file, gmail is able to detect it). What approach should I follow?

Comment: Please keep in mind that there are many other files with executable code that do not end in .exe. An example that is often exploited are screensavers: .scr files. But there are many more. And depending on how you server the files there might be an issue with HTML files containing Java Script.

Comment: but how to achieve above mentioned purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the contents of a zip file even if it is password protected.

If the zip file is password protected all you can do is to check file extensions.
If not protected, you can check contents for executables (exe, scr): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65122